# How to convert multiline to singleline but preserve paragraphs

Tags: text-processing

Say I have a bunch of (markdown) text with each sentence on a separate line (for easier version control in case of typos). Example `file.txt`:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Dictum sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate.
Nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet.

Quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in.
Leo duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa id neque.
Vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros.
```

How can I convert turn each paragraph into a single line so that it looks like:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dictum sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate. Nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet.

Quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in. Leo duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa id neque. Vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus.
```

My idea is to find and replace the newline `\n` character between a fullstop `.` and any non-whitespace character `\S`. I've figured out how to do it in regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/yjBc4f/1) but was wondering if there's a shorter tr/sed/awk equivalent I can use in my bash shell. Something like `cat file.txt | ???`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`perl` has a paragraph mode via the `-00` [`perlrun`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlrun.pod) flag, so if we replace all the internal newlines of your `input` with a space:

```
$ wc -l input
       7 input
$ perl -00 -pe 's/\n(?!\Z)/ /g' input | wc -l
       3
$
```

The `(?!\Z)` bit is to not replace the newlines at the end of each paragraph, thus preserving the paragraph boundaries.

Another option is `lex`. This reveals a few tricky points, notably how to handle `EOF` and whether to always include an ultimate newline (as POSIX demands), and what you define as a paragraph: exactly two newlines, or any number whatsoever?

```
%%

[\n][\n]+ { printf("%s", yytext); }
\n        { int c = input();
            /* TODO book docs say this should return EOF on EOF ?? */
            if (c == 0) {
                putchar('\n');
                yyterminate();
            } else {
                printf(" %c", c);
            }
          }
<<EOF>>   { putchar('\n'); yyterminate(); }

%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return yylex();
}
```

It probably needs more tests than

```
$ make paranlneg
lex  -o lex.paranlneg.c paranlneg.l
egcc -O2 -pipe    -o paranlneg lex.paranlneg.c  -ll
rm -f lex.paranlneg.c
$ perl -E 'say "a\nb\n\nc\nd"' | ./paranlneg
a b

c d
$
```

Comment: Thanks! I've had to modify your script a little bit to handle some edge cases but I'll figure those out myself. Good work :)

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [@thrig's Perl-based answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/479229/65304) but using GNU Awk:

```
$ gawk -vRS= '{$1=$1; printf $0 RT}' file.txt
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Dictum sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate. Nunc faucibus a pellentesque sit amet.

Quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in. Leo duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor massa id neque. Vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros.
```

---

For a quick'n'dirty solution you could use Coreutils `fmt` utility with a suitably large width value:

```
fmt -w1000 file.txt
```

(although by default this will add a double space after each period).

Answer (score 2):

GNU `sed` based approach:

You can use `tr` to replace `<newline>` characters with `<NUL>` characters, then use `sed` to change sequences of two or more consecutive `<NUL>` characters into a double `<newline>` character, then use `tr` to replace remaining `<NUL>` characters with white spaces:

```
$ tr '\n' '\0' <file.txt | sed 's/\o000\{2,\}/\n\n/g' | tr '\0' ' ' | sed --null-data 's/ $/\n/'
```

Here, the last `sed` is only needed to substitute the final remaining space with a new line.

Alternatively (and more concisely) you can instruct `sed` to treat your file as a sequence of null-terminated lines (that is, `sed` considers it a single line) and replace with a single white space all the occurrences of a single new line preceded and followed by a non-space character:

```
$ sed --null-data 's/\([^[:space:]]\)\n\([^[:space:]]\)/\1 \2/g' file.txt
```

This will also preserve vertical spacing between paragraphs, i.e. the number of consecutive new lines. I preferred to search for a non-space character (instead of a dot) followed by a new line just to handle the case of a sentence not ending in a full stop.

Comment: Not as short but I like this approach! Looks a lot more adaptable for handling other use cases :D